# How to parse JSON data and print on terminal in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my Json data :

```
     { 
   "result":"0",
   "school_name":"Global Academy International",
   "school_code":"GAIS",
   "dashboard":"{\"privilege\":[{\"activity_id\":159,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_MYPROFILE\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_DASHBOARD\",\"privilege_id\":1185},{\"activity_id\":159,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_MYTIMETABLE\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_DASHBOARD\",\"privilege_id\":1186},{\"activity_id\":159,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_MYATTENDANCE\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_DASHBOARD\",\"privilege_id\":1188},{\"activity_id\":159,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_MYLEAVESTATUS\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_DASHBOARD\",\"privilege_id\":1189},{\"activity_id\":159,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_MEMO\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_DASHBOARD\",\"privilege_id\":1193},{\"activity_id\":161,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_SUBJECTWISE\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE\",\"privilege_id\":1198},{\"activity_id\":161,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_SUBJECTWISELATE\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE\",\"privilege_id\":1201},{\"activity_id\":162,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_LEAVE_REQUISITION\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_TEACHER_LEAVE\",\"privilege_id\":1203},{\"activity_id\":164,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_ASSIGNMENT\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_STUDENT_ASSIGNMENT\",\"privilege_id\":1206},{\"activity_id\":166,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_SCHOOL_CALENDAR\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_CALENDAR\",\"privilege_id\":1208},{\"activity_id\":168,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_LOGOUT\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_LOGOUT\",\"privilege_id\":1210}],\"resultPrivilege\":\"0\",\"resultProfile\":\"0\",\"profile\":{\"empid\":\"EMP183\",\"name\":\"BACHIR Raji Kashkash\",\"designation\":\"TEACHER\",\"photo_path\":\"/container/school_data/GAIS/photo/Staff/EMP183.jpg\",\"department_name\":\"HIGH SCHOOL - T\"}}",
   "employee_id":"EMP183",
   "school_url":"http://ict.gaiqatar.com"
}
```

I want to print only  this data from jSON data:

```
[{\"activity_id\":159,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_MYPROFILE\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_DASHBOARD\",\"privilege_id\":1185},{\"activity_id\":159,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_MYTIMETABLE\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_DASHBOARD\",\"privilege_id\":1186},{\"activity_id\":168,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_LOGOUT\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_LOGOUT\",\"privilege_id\":1210}]
```

How to get this data from whole jSON data ?

Answer (score 1):

Import the following package:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Decode the json result returned and access the specific field you want:

```
final body = json.decode(response.dashboard);
print(body['privilege']);
```

Basically after parsing your initial json you need to parse the nested field as well (privileges) since it's not a valid json object. Usually I would do this from the server and send a proper json response to the client (flutter).

If this can't be done then you just have to parse the json response, walk through it and parse and nested fields as well.

Edit:

Noticed your json wasn't formatted properly this is an example code. You can run this in dartpad

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final jsonString =  '{\"privilege\":[{\"activity_id\":159,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_MYPROFILE\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_DASHBOARD\",\"privilege_id\":1185},{\"activity_id\":159,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_MYTIMETABLE\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_DASHBOARD\",\"privilege_id\":1186},{\"activity_id\":168,\"privilege_desc\":\"V4_LOGOUT\",\"activity_desc\":\"V4_LOGOUT\",\"privilege_id\":1210}],\"resultPrivilege\":\"0\",\"resultProfile\":\"0\"}';

  final parsedJson = json.decode(jsonString);
  final privilege = parsedJson['privilege'];
  print(privilege);
}
```

Comment: I have try this but it will give this error---The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("result")

Comment: 1. In the future please state what you have tried already and the errors you got, this saves anyone trying to help you a lot of time. 2. You didn't show any of your code so there's no way to tell what went wrong. Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your json is not properly formatted. first format it properly, you can copy and paste your json in any prettify json website and try to format it properly, if problem persists then do let me know.

Comment: do you want to extract the dashboard map from the whole map or only some elements of the dashboard map!

Answer (score 0):

**The Json Data**

```
final jsonData = """{ 
   "result":"0",
   "school_name":"Global Academy International",
   "school_code":"GAIS",
   "dashboard":"{\\"privilege\\":[{\\"activity_id\\":159,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_MYPROFILE\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_DASHBOARD\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1185},{\\"activity_id\\":159,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_MYTIMETABLE\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_DASHBOARD\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1186},{\\"activity_id\\":159,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_MYATTENDANCE\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_DASHBOARD\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1188},{\\"activity_id\\":159,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_MYLEAVESTATUS\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_DASHBOARD\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1189},{\\"activity_id\\":159,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_MEMO\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_DASHBOARD\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1193},{\\"activity_id\\":161,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_SUBJECTWISE\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1198},{\\"activity_id\\":161,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_SUBJECTWISELATE\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1201},{\\"activity_id\\":162,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_LEAVE_REQUISITION\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_TEACHER_LEAVE\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1203},{\\"activity_id\\":164,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_ASSIGNMENT\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_STUDENT_ASSIGNMENT\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1206},{\\"activity_id\\":166,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_SCHOOL_CALENDAR\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_CALENDAR\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1208},{\\"activity_id\\":168,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_LOGOUT\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_LOGOUT\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1210}],\\"resultPrivilege\\":\\"0\\",\\"resultProfile\\":\\"0\\",\\"profile\\":{\\"empid\\":\\"EMP183\\",\\"name\\":\\"BACHIR Raji Kashkash\\",\\"designation\\":\\"TEACHER\\",\\"photo_path\\":\\"/container/school_data/GAIS/photo/Staff/EMP183.jpg\\",\\"department_name\\":\\"HIGH SCHOOL - T\\"}}",
   "employee_id":"EMP183",
   "school_url":"http://ict.gaiqatar.com"
}""";
```

Used double \\ to scape correctly the char "...

And then:

```
final parsedJson = json.decode(jsonData);
print(parsedJson['dashboard']);
```

If you prefer, you can parse only dashboard section to filter some itens programaticaly...

```
final dashboardParsed = json.decode(parsedJson['dashboard']);
print(dashboardParsed);
```

**Final result**

```
final jsonData = """{ 
   "result":"0",
   "school_name":"Global Academy International",
   "school_code":"GAIS",
   "dashboard":"{\\"privilege\\":[{\\"activity_id\\":159,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_MYPROFILE\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_DASHBOARD\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1185},{\\"activity_id\\":159,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_MYTIMETABLE\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_DASHBOARD\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1186},{\\"activity_id\\":159,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_MYATTENDANCE\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_DASHBOARD\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1188},{\\"activity_id\\":159,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_MYLEAVESTATUS\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_DASHBOARD\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1189},{\\"activity_id\\":159,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_MEMO\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_DASHBOARD\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1193},{\\"activity_id\\":161,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_SUBJECTWISE\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1198},{\\"activity_id\\":161,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_SUBJECTWISELATE\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1201},{\\"activity_id\\":162,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_LEAVE_REQUISITION\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_TEACHER_LEAVE\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1203},{\\"activity_id\\":164,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_ASSIGNMENT\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_STUDENT_ASSIGNMENT\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1206},{\\"activity_id\\":166,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_SCHOOL_CALENDAR\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_CALENDAR\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1208},{\\"activity_id\\":168,\\"privilege_desc\\":\\"V4_LOGOUT\\",\\"activity_desc\\":\\"V4_LOGOUT\\",\\"privilege_id\\":1210}],\\"resultPrivilege\\":\\"0\\",\\"resultProfile\\":\\"0\\",\\"profile\\":{\\"empid\\":\\"EMP183\\",\\"name\\":\\"BACHIR Raji Kashkash\\",\\"designation\\":\\"TEACHER\\",\\"photo_path\\":\\"/container/school_data/GAIS/photo/Staff/EMP183.jpg\\",\\"department_name\\":\\"HIGH SCHOOL - T\\"}}",
   "employee_id":"EMP183",
   "school_url":"http://ict.gaiqatar.com"
}""";


final parsedJson = json.decode(jsonData);
print(parsedJson['dashboard']);

final dashboardParsed = json.decode(parsedJson['dashboard']);
print(dashboardParsed);
```

I Scaped \" because I'm storing the string into a var, if it comes from your web api, should work too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the perfect solution,It can be parsed no matter how long it is, and it is still in json format, which can be easily parsed

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:convert';
...
...
log('${jsonEncode(responseData)}');
```